# Need a Fake data generator for Java console application

Tags: java, console-application, data-generation

I need a Fake Data Generator (e.g., For a person's personal information like first name, last name, email and all) for console based jdbc application.
Because I want to add those data of random person to MySQL database.

My code for MySQL as below :

```
String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant";
String user = "root";
String password = "root";

conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
if (conn1 != null) {
    System.out.println("Connected to the database restaurant");
   // I want add data generator here.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [DataFactory](http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/generate-test-data-with-datafactory/). It generated names (even some specific region names), addresses, birth dates or other dates, general random strings, you can even give it some arrays of random stuff to generate from, etc

**Edit: usage example**

In order to get different output each time, create it with your seed for `Random()`. The best seed is nano time:

```
DataFactory df1 = DataFactory.create(System.nanoTime());
```

Everytime you create it, you will get different output.

Comment: Yes, it's good, but if I tried with 100 random record and again I tried with 100 then it'll return same records.
So it's not feasible for me.

Comment: Yea, you're right. Author of this library hardcoded random seed to 93285:
https://github.com/swung/datafactory/blob/master/src/org/datafactory/DataFactory.java

Comment: Do you have any other solution like jfairy and all?

Comment: I used this once, i didn't need repeat so didn't notice this before. I will try to fork this project and fix this, see will it help. Will inform you today how it went.

Comment: My mistake, I was working with forked and false datafactory library. You should use original https://github.com/andygibson/datafactory but, you must use specific constructor. I will update my answer with details.

Comment: Hi,

But i have used jar file so how do i do?
please advice.

Comment: Did you downloaded it from maven repository or?

Comment: Actually i want this is on console based application.
So how do i use it please advice?
Or provide me the updated jar if possible.
Thank you

Comment: Download it from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fluttercode.datafactory/datafactory/0.8 and import it as library. Or you can download source code and include it in your project (less effort).

Comment: I have download it and use it as a library but i got same issue.

Comment: Ohh got it now,
Only one error "The method create(long) is undefined for the type DataFactory"
If i use only jar file then it'll give me this error but if i use the code then it'll working fine.
Please update jar if possible.

Comment: That must be done by library owner. It looks like he didnt do anything there for 5 years, so we can't expect new things from him...

Comment: Okay Adnan, Thnx for the help.
I'll work with your code.
Thank you once again.

Comment: Hi Adnan,

Please advice on this question if you have time and if you have idea for the same.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929598/add-lots-of-data-with-some-time-interval-in-java

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Adnan,

Remember datafactory?
I need more details on it like company name, country, state, zip, website.
Can you please how do i get these all?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use jFairy. This will best suited for you.
The github link for a project : https://github.com/Codearte/jfairy/tree/master/src/main

Code Example:

```
  Fairy fairy = Fairy.create();
    Person person = fairy.person();
    System.out.println(person.fullName());
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried with this, but i got the error on this page of jfair "VATIdentificationNumberProvider.java".
So it's not wroking.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout [randomizer](https://github.com/android-Infoedge/randomizer) for random data generation.This library helps to create random data from given Model class.Checkout below example code.

```
public class Person {

   @FirstName
   String mFirstName;

   @LastName
   String mLastName;

   @Email
   String  mEmailId;

}

//Generate random 100 Person(Model Class) object 
Generator<Person> generator = new Generator<>(Person.class);  
List<Person> persons = generator.generate(100);
```

As there are many built in data generator is accessible using annotation,You also can build custom data generator.I suggest you to go through documentation provided on library page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dummycreator library for generating dummy objects [dummycreator](https://github.com/bbottema/lorem-ipsum-objects).

It can be used like this

```
public static <T> T create(final Class<T> clazz) {
    return dummyCreator.create(clazz);
}
```

More, you can specify bindings for specifying how to generate some classes.

```
static {
    bindings.add(String.class, new RandomStringFactory());
    bindings.add(Examination.class, new RandomExaminationFactory());
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for reply.
But i'm not getting exactly.
I have add this jar in my project.
But If  i need persons random info then what i need to do.
please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently authored a library called MockNeat. It allows you to bootstrap data generation.

On the wiki page there is [detailed tutorial](https://www.mockneat.com/tutorial/) on how you can programatically generate SQL Inserts for your application.