# Add lots of data with some time interval in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to add records I database table with some interval of time using jdbc.

For ex., I want to add 100000 records in 10 sec interval so it'll insert 10000/sec.

My code of MySQL as below :

```
String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz";
String user = "root";
String password = "root";
conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
if (conn1 != null) {
    System.out.println("Connected to the database xyz");
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){ // where n is no. of record that I want to insert
        // Here is my insert logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what is the question actually ?

Comment: I have lots of data which I need to insert into database but there is one condition is that I want to add those data with some time interval.
For ex., I have 100000 data and i'll input that I want to add those data in 10 sec then data will add like 100000/10 = 10000 data per sec.

Comment: @yogeshjalodara Don't know why you would want to limit it, but Thread.sleep(long milliseconds); is the method you are looking for..

Comment: Then It seems its related with performance.

Comment: Actually guys, it's my client's requirement so i need to do this one.
And also check my updated answer.
There are total 2 inputs which are getting from users :
1) No. records  (variable "n" in the code)
2) Time interval.

Comment: So can you do faster than 10000/sec?

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Are you planning on pulling numbers out of thin air, using advanced AerialExtraction algorithm? What's the plan if the rows being inserted already exist?

Comment: Data is randomly generated from data generator.

Comment: You can able to use [java.util.TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to insert new batch to DB by timer.
Such as
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {...}, 0, 1000);. If executing by exact time period is required. And into run() method write code to insert. For sure firstly you should calculate size of batch

Comment: Hi @anbat,

I like this solution, it's very near to my requirement, but one thing is that it's continuously add data in every 1 Sec but I want to add logic like when my data is over then it will stop automatically.

Comment: Just keep in memory some variable for count of processed data such as [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) or any volatile. Decrement and check this each step and stop timer when you will finish

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?
Or you can add a new answer with code.
Thank you.

Comment: FYI, inserting data into a local MySQL, with batch updates, I need to increase the concurrency to achieve 10000 rows/sec. Roughly I need 100 connections all doing batch insert. With ~700 connections, I can do 27000/sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@yogesh-jalodara In my comments I meant something like that

```
final long loopDuration = 1;//second
final long totalSize = 100000;
final long timeInterval = 10;
final AtomicLong batchNumber = new AtomicLong((long)Math.ceil((double) timeInterval / loopDuration));
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //insert logic
        if (batchNumber.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }

    }
}, 0, loopDuration * 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using batch queries, You effectively reduce database round-trip,  You save a lot of time spent on network latency, which results in better performance of Java application.

```
public class MySQLJdbcExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {

        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root"); 
        String query = "insert into employee values (?,?,NULL)";
        PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        int batchSize = 100;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int count = 0; count < 1000; count++) {
            pStatement.setString(1, Integer.toString(count));
            pStatement.setString(2, "Employee" + count);
            pStatement.addBatch();

            if (count % batchSize == 0) {
                pStatement.executeBatch();
            }
        }

       pStatement.executeBatch() ; //for remaining batch queries if total record is odd no.

     // conn.commit();
        pStatement.close();
        conn.close();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000; //in seconds
        System.out.println("Total time required to execute 1000 queries using PreparedStatement with JDBC batch insert is :" + elapsedTime);



    }
}
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/01/jdbc-batch-insert-and-update-example-java-prepared-statement.html#ixzz47Bgqyx64