# How to store objects in memory and flush them to a destination after Max(amount, time)

Tags: java, caching, max, bulkinsert

My `Spring Boot` application gets input `Student` and needs to write it to the DB.

I can write to the DB right after getting the `Student` object, but I like to make it more efficient, by accumulating several students in memory and then to save to the DB a bulk of `Students`.

So I'm looking for a solution that will enable to cache the Students for `Max(some duration, number of students)` and will enable to save the Students in one bulk once the limit was reached.

There is an option to write the code with `Thread` and such, but it seems like this problem was probably solved before.

There are the [caffeine](https://www.baeldung.com/java-caching-caffeine) and [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) libraries, but I still didn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Spring or JavaSE (jdbc)?

Comment: @SvilenYanovski  Spring boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add lots of data with some time interval in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929598/add-lots-of-data-with-some-time-interval-in-java)

Comment: See the [writebehind](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/a698999b294d4cc64e10dd41ee081afe7ca40336/examples/write-behind-rxjava/src/test/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/examples/writebehind/rxjava/WriteBehindCacheWriterTest.java#L61-L84) example, which uses rxjava. Similarly consider using Spring's Reactor as this is exactly what those libraries try to solve elegantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to have a queue with objects awaiting flushing.
Flush will be triggered by 2 events: by schedule (some duration exceeded) and by size (queue size exceeded).

In pure Java it can be implemented using `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`:

```
public abstract class FlushingCache<T> {

  private final Duration maxDuration;
  private final int maxSize;
  private final List<T> queue = new ArrayList<>();
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

  public FlushingCache(Duration maxDuration, int maxSize) {
    this.maxDuration = maxDuration;
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::doFlush,
        maxDuration.getSeconds(),
        maxDuration.getSeconds(),
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public synchronized void enqueue(T element) {
    println("Enqueueing element " + element);
    queue.add(element);
    if (queue.size() >= maxSize) {
      doFlush();
    }
  }

  private synchronized void doFlush() {
    List<T> batch = new ArrayList<>(queue);
    println("Flushing batch " + batch);
    flush(batch);
    queue.clear();
  }

  // The login of flushing to DB will be implemented in the sub-classes
  protected abstract void flush(List<T> batch);
}
```

With the following test data

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  FlushingCache<String> studentsCache = new FlushingCache<>(Duration.ofSeconds(10), 3) {
    @Override
    protected void flush(List<String> batch) {
      println("### FLUSH TO DB " + batch);
    }
  };

  studentsCache.enqueue("1");
  studentsCache.enqueue("2");
  studentsCache.enqueue("3");

  studentsCache.enqueue("4");
}

private static void println(String message) {
  System.out.println(LocalTime.now().withNano(0).toString() + ": " + message);
}
```

The result is

```
16:07:17: Enqueueing element 1
16:07:17: Enqueueing element 2
16:07:17: Enqueueing element 3
16:07:17: Flushing batch [1, 2, 3]
16:07:17: ### FLUSH TO DB [1, 2, 3]
16:07:17: Enqueueing element 4
16:07:27: Flushing batch [4]
16:07:27: ### FLUSH TO DB [4]
```

Queue is flushed to DB when size reaches 3 or every 10 seconds.

In Spring Boot application instead of `ScheduledExecutorService` you can use `@Scheduled`.

Enable scheduling with `@EnableScheduling`

```
@Component
public class StudentFlushingCache {

  private final List<T> queue = new ArrayList<>();

  @Value("${student.flushing-cache.max-size}")
  private final int maxSize;

  @Scheduled(
      fixedDelayString = "${student.flushing-cache.fixed-delay}",
      initialDelayString = "${student.flushing-cache.initial-delay}")
  public void flushPeriodically() {
     doFlush();
  }

  public synchronized void enqueue(T element) {
    /* ... */
  }

  private synchronized void doFlush() {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: jpa/jdbc batch inserts spare you the queue and make the difference regarding performance

Comment: This approach allows "flushing" not to the DB only but to any destination, e.g. REST API etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:
1. Create singleton class to hold the Students

```
public enum MyCache {
INSTANCE(new HashMap<>());

private Map<String, Student> students;

private MyCache(Map<String, Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}...getter, setter}
```

2. Create StudentService, and add there method to push the new Student into the Cache: `MyCache.INSTANCE.getStudents().push(...)`
3. Create Scheduled service to persist the cache:

   @Configuration
   @EnableScheduling
   public class ScheduledService {

   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60*60*1000)
   public void scheduledTask() {
       1. Get the cache
       2. Check if the limit (num students) is reached
       3. Persist the Students - studentRepository.saveAll(students)
       4. Empty cache - list.clear()
   }
   }