# How to store a temporarily created object in spring boot run?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, heap-memory

I have a service constructed under spring boot. During the spring boot run, I want to cache/ temporarily store some objects generated during the boot run.

- Wondering how to do that?
- What is the best place to hold these objects in memory?
- Adding the object to applicationContext?

Thanks

Comment: for how long you intend to keep those objects in memory?

Comment: Does this solution help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935297/how-to-store-objects-in-memory-and-flush-them-to-a-destination-after-maxamount

Comment: @GuilhermeStella I only plan to keep those objects in the memory during the boot run.

Comment: @GuilhermeStella I don't plan to use DB for solving this problem